# Angular Event Binder Error - function parameters converting numbers to strings when passed as a value

Tags: angular

I'm super new to Angular, and I'm getting some super weird behaviour from the (click) event binder that I can't solve.

I take user inputs as numbers in my component.html:

```
<input type="number" name="width" placeholder="Add a door width" required #width>
<input type="number" name="height" placeholder="Add a door height" required #height>
```

I then pass to my component.ts via a button (click):

```
<button (click)="createDoor(width.value, height.value, type.value, name.value)">Add door</button>
```

Whereupon they are received by the createDoor function:

```
createDoor( width: number, height: number, type: string, name: string) {
  const payload = { width_in: width, height_in: height, type, name};
  this.http.post<Door>(`${this.baseURL}/door`, payload).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.doors.push(response);        
    }
  );
}
```

Angular is not happy:

```
    Error: src/app/door/door.component.html:34:33 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    
    34     <button (click)="createDoor(width.value, height.value, type.value, name.value)">Add door</button>
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      src/app/door/door.component.ts:7:16
        7   templateUrl: './door.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component DoorComponent.
```

I can successfully pass raw numbers, or variables assigned as raw numbers, just not number values.
I am absolutely stumped. The only thing I can think of is that the event binder isn't doing type checking properly, but that's me grasping in the dark.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

input values in html are strings, even if it is input type=number.
to fix it, convert strings to numbers explicitly

```
<button (click)="createDoor(+width.value, +height.value, type.value, name.value)">
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, I'm actually quite ashamed to admit that I didn't know that about input values!